# Convert XMLDocument to DataSet ASP.Net 1.1

Tags: xml, dataset, asp.net-1.1

I need to convert XMLDocument to DataSet in ASP.Net. I do not want To Save the XMLData to any physical location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use xmlDocument class to read the xml file and save the data to dataset. [Here is an example](http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/3489611) about how you can use xmlDocument to read XML files.

This code is pretty old. Havent tried it

XmlDocument xdoc = MethodReturnsXmlDocument();

// convert to DataSet

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

ds.ReadXml(new XmlNodeReader(xdoc));

[Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/VB/XML/LoadxmldocumenttoDataSet.htm) is another example for you.